terraform using data section with for_each
I'm trying to create resources by passing configuration in json and have a resource loop over the json.  However part of the same json contains values that need to be used in a data section.
[
{
  "username": "administrator",
  "password": "password",
  "domain_name": "test.io",
  "dns": "[10.10.1.6]",
  "vpc_name": "Sandbox*",
  "subnet_name": "*private*",
  "org_unit": "OU=test,DC=awstest,DC=io"
},
{
  "domain": "awstest.io",
  "username": "administrator",
  "password": "password2"
}
]

The terraform I have is
locals {
  DirectoryServices = jsondecode(var.json)
}

data "aws_vpc" "this" {
  for_each = local.DirectoryServices
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = [each.value.vpc_name]
  }
}

data "aws_subnets" "this" {
  for_each = local.DirectoryServices
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = [each.value.subnet_name]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [data.aws_vpc.this.id]
  }
}

locals {
  subnets = slice(data.aws_subnets.this.ids, 0, 2)
}

resource "aws_directory_service_directory" "connector" {
  for_each = local.DirectoryServices

  name     = each.value.domain_name
  password = each.value.password
  size     = each.value.size
  type     = "ADConnector"

  connect_settings {
    customer_dns_ips  = each.value.dns
    customer_username = each.value.username
    subnet_ids        = data.aws_subnets.this.ids
    vpc_id            = data.aws_vpc.this.id
  }
}

Is there a way to use the values from the json and use them in the data section filters and then reference the correct vpc and subnet items returned from the data sections?
I've been scratching my head over this for ages now, any pointers on how to do this would have really appreciated.
Thanks

It is currently unclear exactly what you are asking, and it may be beneficial to demonstrate current versus expected behavior. However, it is also worth noting that files with JSON strings are valid for TF input variable files: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#variable-definitions-tfvars-files. That would eliminate your intermediary local declaration and enable proper variable type definitions, and both would make using the values much easier for you.

I'll close this off and rewrite it, thanks!

for_each is indeed quite tricky in Terraform

You don't need brackets when using each
When addressing other resources use each.key as an array index
In slice add [*] to receive an array of subnets

This seems to deliver valid terraform:
variable "json" {
  type = string
}

locals {
  DirectoryServices = jsondecode(var.json)
}

data "aws_vpc" "this" {
  for_each = local.DirectoryServices
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = each.value.vpc_name
  }
}

data "aws_subnets" "this" {
  for_each = local.DirectoryServices
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = each.value.subnet_name
  }
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = data.aws_vpc.this[each.key].id
  }
}

locals {
  subnets = slice(data.aws_subnets.this[*].ids, 0, 2)
}

resource "aws_directory_service_directory" "connector" {
  for_each = local.DirectoryServices

  name     = each.value.domain_name
  password = each.value.password
  size     = each.value.size
  type     = "ADConnector"

  connect_settings {
    customer_dns_ips  = each.value.dns
    customer_username = each.value.username
    subnet_ids        = data.aws_subnets.this[each.key].ids
    vpc_id            = data.aws_vpc.this[each.key].id
  }
}


thanks for your help.  Seems like I spoke too quickly about needing to rewrite the question!
However I'm getting this error when I run a plan
│ Error: Invalid for_each argument │  │   on main.tf line 6, in data "aws_vpc" "this": │    6:   for_each = local.DirectoryServices │     ├──────────────── │     │ local.DirectoryServices is tuple with 2 elements │  │ The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have │ provided a value of type tuple.

Sorry I can't get the code to format correctly :/

use ``` before and after the block to format is as code: https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks

@Steve you can find your answer here, probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71793574/iterate-over-json-using-terraform. But maybe you should indeed review your question, the JSON that you provide looks strange, I would expect it to always have same properties. But your JSON contains array of 2 different objects, which is quite strange.
